# How to get Bash version number in OS X

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I am writing a install script which needs Bash 4.x. This install script can be used on OSX too. I am aware that on Linux systems I can get Bash version by checking with `echo $BASH_VERSION` env variable but how do I get the bash version in Darwin? Running `bash --version` will give:

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.33(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

This is *not* the output I want. I want the output to be just the version number, specially just the main version number.

Comment: How about just extracting the part you're interested in? Something like `bash --version | head -1 | awk '{print $4}'`

Comment: On my Mac OS X 10.10.2 Yosemite, `echo $BASH_VERSION` yields
`3.2.57(1)-release`.  Is that not what you need?  Or can it not be mangled into what you want?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`echo $BASH_VERSION` works on Mac OS X as well:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
3.2.57(1)-release
```

If you need to check if they have a newer bash installed, (such as via Homebrew or MacPorts) by calling the `bash` that is in their path, you can just execute that command from within that version of `bash`:

```
$ bash -c 'echo $BASH_VERSION'
4.3.30(1)-release
```

To get just one component of the version, there is an [array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays), `BASH_VERSINFO`, so you can access each element individually. If you just want the major version (this is on my system, where my login shell is Bash 3 but I have Bash 4 installed for scripting):

```
$ echo ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}
3
$ bash -c 'echo ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}'
4
```

You can see the full contents of the array as well:

```
$ echo "${BASH_VERSINFO[@]}"
3 2 57 1 release x86_64-apple-darwin14
$ bash -c 'echo "${BASH_VERSINFO[@]}"'
4 3 30 1 release x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
```

Comment: Note that if you aren't actually in bash at the moment, you can use `bash -c 'echo $BASH_VERSION'`. This'll also work in both OS X and linux.

Comment: @sindhus Updated my answer on how to use the `BASH_VERSINFO` array to access just one component of the version at a time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following one liner to extract the version number:

```
bash --version | awk 'NR==1{print $4}'
```

> user@ubuntu-server:~$ bash --version |awk 'NR==1{print $4}'
>
> 4.3.11(1)-release

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the version number will always be the 4th "word" of output?

Answer (score 2):

I seem to be able to use this:

```
echo ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}
3
echo ${BASH_VERSINFO[1]}
2
echo ${BASH_VERSINFO[2]}
57
```

and

```
echo $BASH_VERSION
3.2.57(1)-release
```